# задача на условие

Tags: python

```
    s = 'hello world'

    for i in s:
        if i == 'o':
            s == s.upper()
        else:
            s == s.lower
    print(s)

# hello world
```

подскажите пожалуйста почему переменная не переводится в верхний регистр при том что условие выполняется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Потому что вместо `=` написано `==`
2. А кто `lower` вызывать будет?
3. Всё равно не заработает потому что регистр останется в соответствии с проверкой последней буквы строки - нижний